# This program shows segmentation fault,I think infinite recursion occurs.Can you suggest me the correction

Tags: c, recursion

```
#include <stdio.h>
int f(int n)
{
  if(n <= 1)
    return 1;
  if(n%2 == 0)
    return f(n/2);
  return f((n-1)/2) + f((n-1)/2+1);
}

/*To test above function */
int main()
{
  int a = 11;
  printf("%d", f(11));
  getchar();
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: The program prints 5 for me with no segmentation fault. That function doesn't go into infinite recursion, not for n=11 anyway.

Comment: Initially, it gives answer and then fault occurs after a second or so.

Comment: Would you mind giving us more information on your hardware, OS and development tools (compiler, C library version etc)?

Comment: if it does give the answer, then it means that f() successfully returns, so no infinite recursion here. Something else is the root of the evil here, maybe getchar() but I can't imagine why.

Answer (score 1):

Why not just to trace it in debugger, and see what's goind wrong?

Comment: This should probably just be a comment against the question - it's not really an answer in any meaningful sense of the word.

Comment: Well, I think it is the right answer. To any question "my code crashes" the correct answer is "Use the debugger to analyze the crash". More often than not the problem is obvious in the debugger.

Answer (score 1):

This code compiles and runs just fine for me. The result is 5. Have you tried the `explicit` keyword to see if it is an optimization flaw? EDIT: If the problem is `getchar()` the problem could be your operating system at run time or your library at compile time. Is that a clean compile? What compiler are you using?

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong with this program, it doesn't give me any sort of infinite loop or seg fault (and since you have the <=1 condition, the program will not crash out for sure).
Something tells me that your machine here is faulty for some reason... maybe lack of memory or confilcting programs? Or even compiler freaking out? (that one already happened to me). Try to run the code on other machine if possible and find out if it still gives you seg fault or not